# INSERT Query with array_search() or SELECT Subquery would be faster?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, query-performance

I have two Arrays with Categories like the following example:

```
$apply_func['categories'] = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'];
$apply_func['subcategories'] = ['H','I','J','K','L','M','N'];
```

Which I apply a **custom function** on them like the following:

```
foreach ($apply_func as $name => $values) {
    $$name = custom_func($values);
}
```

Right now I have three Tables related like the following:

```
categories[id, category_name]--------
                                     |------ cat_sub[id, category_id, subcategory_id]
subcategories[id, subcategory_name]--
```

What I'm confused about is What method shall I do in `INSERT` for this specific **Array**

```
$cat_sub = [
    ['category' => 'A', 'subcategory' => 'H'],
    ['category' => 'B', 'subcategory' => 'I'],
    ['category' => 'C', 'subcategory' => 'J'],
    ['category' => 'D', 'subcategory' => 'K'],
    ['category' => 'E', 'subcategory' => 'L'],
    ['category' => 'F', 'subcategory' => 'M'],
    ['category' => 'G', 'subcategory' => 'N']
];
```

to get this result on the `cat_sub.table` like this:

```
[category_id , subcategory_id]
[1           , 1             ]
[2           , 2             ]
[3           , 3             ]
[4           , 4             ]
[5           , 5             ]
[6           , 6             ]
[7           , 7             ]
```

---

I have two methods I thought about:

1. **array_search()**

   ```
   //Cat_Sub
   $query = "INSERT INTO cat_sub (category_id, subcategory_id) VALUES ";
   foreach ($cat_sub as $catsub) {
     $category = array_search($catsub['category'], $categories)+1;
     $subcategory = array_search($catsub['subcategory'], $subcategories)+1;
     $cats[] = "($category, $subcategory)";
   }
   $query .= implode(',', $cats);
   $pdo->prepare($query)->execute();

   //Categories, Subcategories
   foreach ($apply_func as $name => $values) {
       $query = "INSERT INTO $name (".str_replace('ies', 'y', $name)."_name)  VALUES ";
       foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
           $$name[$key] = "($value)";
       }
       $query .= implode(',', $$name);
   }
   $pdo->prepare($query)->execute();
   ```

---

2. **SELECT SubQuery**

   ```
   //Categories, Subcategories
   foreach ($apply_func as $name => $values) {

       $query = "INSERT INTO $name (".str_replace('ies', 'y', $name)."_name) VALUES ";
       foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
           $$name[$key] = "($value)";
       }
       $query .= implode(',', $$name);
   }
   $pdo->prepare($query)->execute();    


   //Cat_Sub
   $query = "INSERT INTO cat_sub (category_id, subcategory_id) VALUES ";
   foreach ($cat_sub as $catsub) {
     $cats[] = "(
                    (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE category_name = '".$catsub['category']."'),
                    (SELECT id FROM subcategories WHERE subcategory_name = '".$catsub['subcategory']."')
                )";
   }
   $query .= implode(',', $cats);
   $pdo->prepare($query)->execute();
   ```

---

Both methods does the Job, But I don't know Which method is better to be used in this case.

P.S. The Tables are well Indexed and all `id`s are in `AI` mode, The actual **Arrays** has **+100,000 record**

Comment: Both methods [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). So just throw a coin, if you are going to use one of them.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I find the `SELECT SubQuery` method safer And doesn't **smell**, Since it will always get the correct `id` from the Tables, But I still have concerns about its Performance in such a case, Since it is over `100,000 record` doubled to `200,000 SELECT SubQuery` but It is **Indexed**, Which still confuses me If it would be faster or slower than the `array_search()` method, But If there is a better method other than these two, I would like to know it.

Comment: Code smells I mean: `$$name`, `INSERT INTO $name` and any SQL query in a loop.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel oh yes, That I double checked it to make sure it is working properly, Does using the `$$` makes any problem?

Comment: The names "category" and "subcategory" imply a 1:many relationship.  Such should _not_ be implemented via 3rd table (`cat_sub`), but rather a `cat_id` in the `subcat` table.  Fix either the terminology or the schema.